# NullPointerException in Page object Model class

Tags: java, selenium, nullpointerexception, testng, pom.xml

i am getting a NullPointerException from testng and i really dont know what i am doing wrong. I am trying to launch an iOS test. The BaseMobile class contains my Appium driver and its initialisation. The Picker_View_Objects contains my Page objects. Mobile_Test and PickerView_Method contains my Test and methods. Please help me figure out what i am doing wrong:
Here is the error message:

```
    public class BaseMobile {

            public IOSDriver<MobileElement> getURL() throws MalformedURLException{
                DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
                capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 8");
                capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/path_to_.app");
                capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.IOS);
                capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.IOS_XCUI_TEST);
                capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 60);

                IOSDriver<MobileElement> driver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),capability);
                Picker_View_Objects pwo = new Picker_View_Objects(driver);
                return driver;
            }


    public class Picker_View_Objects extends BaseMobile{

        IOSDriver<MobileElement> driver ;
        public Picker_View_Objects(IOSDriver<MobileElement> driver) throws MalformedURLException {
            driver = this.driver;
            PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), getClass());

        }


        @iOSXCUITFindBy(xpath = "//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name='Picker View']")
        static IOSElement picker_view;

        public static IOSElement get_picker_view() {
            return picker_view;
        }


    public class Mobile_Test extends PickerView_Method{

        @Test
        public void click_on_picker_view() {
            PickerView_Method.click_picker_view();
        }

    }


    public class PickerView_Method {

        public static void click_picker_view() {
            Picker_View_Objects.get_picker_view().click();
        }

    }


ERROR MESSAGE:
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.1
FAILED: click_on_picker_view
java.lang.NullPointerException
at methods.PickerView_Method.click_picker_view(PickerView_Method.java:8)
at tests.Mobile1.Mobile_Test.click_on_picker_view(Mobile_Test.java:11)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: (1) do this -> public class PickerView_Method extends Picker_View_Objects  and then run one more time (2) Your test doesn't know anything about your driver

Comment: thanks @MikeASP. I figured out the way to go was to do:

public class PickerView_Method extends BaseMobile{
 
 
   public PickerView_Method() throws MalformedURLException {
  driver = super.driver;
 }